# Why am I getting "invalid argument being supplied for foreach"?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am creating a search within my database and when I used the foreach construct for my results to be echoed I'm getting "invalid argument being  supplied for foreach..". What I don't understand is why this error is coming up because the foreach containing my errors works fine.

```
if (empty($errors)){
    $results = search_results($keywords);
    $results_num = count($results);

    foreach ($results as $result){
        echo '<p> <strong>', $result['TITLE'], '</strong> </p>';
    }
} else {
    foreach($errors as $error){
        echo $error, '</br>';
    }
}
```

The part of the search_results function that's being focused on is this

```
$results = "SELECT TITLE FROM occupationalinfo WHERE $where"; 
$results_num = ($results = mysql_query($results)) ? mysql_num_rows($results): 0;

if ($results_num === 0){
    return false;
}else{
    while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $returned_results[] = array(
            'title' => $results_row['TITLE']
        );      
    }
}
```

I am still new to programming so I understand if there is something I may have missed or just not quite get. I would greatly appreciate any tips or constructive criticism.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing into `foreach` what you think you are passing?

Comment: It would help if you included the whole `search_results` function.

Comment: Probably `$results` is not traverseable (eg: array)

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($results)` and `var_dump($errors)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($results_num === 0){
    return false;
}
```

I'd bet this is executing, so it's returning `false`. You cannot apply `foreach` to `false`. Perhaps you should `return array()`, or just check for `false`:

```
$results = search_results($keywords);
if ($results !== false) {
    $results_num = count($results);

    foreach ($results as $result){
        echo '<p> <strong>',$result['TITLE'],'</strong> </p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try php function `is_array()`.

```
if (empty($errors)){
           $results = search_results($keywords);
            if(is_array($results)){
               foreach ($results as $result){
                 echo '<p> <strong>'. $result['TITLE'] .'</strong></p>';
               }
            } else {
                echo "<p> <strong>empty</strong></p>";
            }
    }
```

or

```
 if (empty($errors)){
        $results = search_results($keywords);
        if(is_array($results)){
             $results_num = count($results);
             foreach ($results as $result){
               echo '<p> <strong>'. $result['TITLE']. '</strong> </p>';
             }
        }        
    } else {
        foreach($errors as $error){
            echo $error, '</br>';
        }
    }
```